# Finding general solution of $x'' + 2k x' + \omega^2 x = 0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

**Problem:** Let $k, \omega > 0$. Give the general solution of the differential equation \begin{align*} x'' + 2k x' + \omega^2 x = 0 \end{align*} for a function $x(t)$. Give the general solution for the case that (i) $k > \omega > 0$ and for the case that (ii) $0 < k < \omega$.

**Attempt:** This a homogeneous differential equation of second order with constant coefficients. Hence the characteristic equation of this ODE is \begin{align*} r^2 + 2k r + \omega^2 = 0. \end{align*} The solutions of this equation are \begin{align*} r_1 = -k + \sqrt{k^2 - \omega^2} \quad \text{and} \quad r_2 = -k - \sqrt{k^2 - \omega^2} \end{align*} Now I'm not sure how to write down the general solution. For case (i) we will have that $r^2 - \omega^2 > 0$ and so the solutions will be real. For case (ii) they will be complex. We cannot have that $r_1 = r_2$, unless $k^2 - \omega^2 = 0$. Should I just write \begin{align*} x(t) = c_1 e^{r_1 t} + c_2 e^{r_2 t}, \end{align*} with $c_1, c_2$ arbitrary constants?

Comment: In the case that $k^2=\omega^2,$ it isn't that simple. Otherwise, that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three solutions:

if the roots are real(not same  or k>w) the solution is
$$\begin{align*} x(t) = c_1 e^{r_1 t} + c_2 e^{r_2 t}, \end{align*}$$
if the roots are real (same or r=w) the solution is
$$x(t) = c_1 e^{r_1 t} + c_2 te^{r_1 t}$$
if the roots are (real+complex or $k<w$) the solution is

$$x=e^{r1 t}(A\cos(r2 x)+B\sin(r2 x))$$
so
$r1=real part$ and $r2=imaginary part$

Answer (score 1):

Notice, if $k^2-\omega^2<0$, the roots are complex given as 
$$r_1, \ r_2=-k\pm i\sqrt{\omega^2-k^2}$$

then you need to write the solution as follows $$x(t)=e^{-kt}\left(c_1\cos t\sqrt{\omega^2-k^2}+c_2\sin t\sqrt{\omega^2-k^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, you have as a general solution $$x=e^{-kt}(A\cos (t\sqrt{\omega^2-k^2})+B\sin(t\sqrt{\omega^2-k^2}))$$

Comment: What if the roots of the characteristic equation are complex AND are repeated (i.e. they are the same)? Is this possible? Or do they necessarily always come in conjugate pairs?

Comment: If $k<\omega$ the roots are complex conjugates. They aren't repeated roots as this only occurs if $k=\omega$

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly odd way of doing it, that separates some of the structure and reduces to an easier equation: set $x(t)=e^{-kt}y(t)$ (where do I get this from? Well, looking at the roots of the charactistic equation, naturally... It's also possible to think of it as a sort of integrating factor.). The derivatives are
$$ x' = e^{-kt}(y'-ky), x'' = e^{-kt}(y'' -2ky' + k^2y), $$
and putting these into the DE, the $e^{-kt}$ cancels, giving
$$ 0 = (y''-2ky'+k^2y)+2k(y'-ky) + \omega^2 y = y''+(\omega^2-k^2)y. $$
Ah, but we know the solutions to this equation: if $\omega^2-k^2=0$, then
$$ y''=0 \implies y=At+B $$
for some constants $A,B$. If $\omega^2-k^2>0$, this is the simple harmonic motion equation, which has solutions of the form
$$ A\cos{\sqrt{\omega^2-k^2}t}+B\sin{\sqrt{\omega^2-k^2}t}, $$
whereas if $\omega^2-k^2<0$, this introduces a factor of $i$ into the above solutions, and using the relationship between trigonometric and hyperbolic functions implies that the general solution can be written as
$$ A\cosh{\sqrt{k^2-\omega^2}t}+B\sinh{\sqrt{k^2-\omega^2}t} $$
or
$$ Ae^{\sqrt{k^2-\omega^2}t}+Be^{\sqrt{k^2-\omega^2}t}; $$
which form is most useful depends on the initial conditions. For the $x$ solution, just multiply these by $e^{-kt}$, of course.